# Why does my function not print the sorted array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, methods

```
# Methods for calculating
# print out the input that the user entered
def PrintScores(*numbers)
    numbers.each {|x| print x.join(" ")}
    puts
end

#print out the scores in ascending order
def ListScores(*numbers)
    numbers.sort!
    print numbers
end

# Main function
out_file = File.new("out.txt", "w")

puts "Enter the scores you wish to have our stats program look into? "
user_input = gets.chomp

input_array = user_input.split(" ")

input_array.map! do |x|
    x.to_i
end

PrintScores(input_array)
ListScores(input_array)
```

The `ListScores` function still prints the array in the order in which I entered it, and I can not figure out why.

Comment: you should use `ListScores(numbers)` instead of `ListScores(*numbers)`

Comment: Don't create methods that puts or prints. As ruby has a method to put and print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The ListScores function still prints the array in the order in which I entered it and i can not figure out why?*

In your current code, `input_array` is an instance of `Array` class which is passed as an argument to `ListScores` method. `ListScores` is expecting `splat arguments`, so `numbers` become an *Array* containing a single Array element(i.e., `input_array` contents). This is the reason you see the array in the same order when you try to sort it.

For example:

```
> user_input = gets.chomp
3 2 8 5 1
 => "3 2 8 5 1" 
> input_array = user_input.split(" ")
 => ["3", "2", "8", "5", "1"] 
>   input_array.map! do |x|
>         x.to_i
>   end
 => [3, 2, 8, 5, 1] 
> ListScores(input_array)
[[3, 2, 8, 5, 1]] => nil ## Notice Array with single Array element [[]]
```

`splat operator`(`*`) is used in methods when you have a need for variable parameter list.
In your case, you don't need splat operator in `PrintScores` and `ListScores` method.

```
def PrintScores(numbers) ## <-- Removed splat operator
    numbers.each {|x| print x.join(" ")}
    puts
end

#print out the scores in ascending order
def ListScores(numbers) ## <-- Removed splat operator
    numbers.sort!
    print numbers
end
```

Sample output:

```
>   ListScores(input_array)
 [1, 2, 3, 5, 8] => nil
```

**NOTE:** Its advisable to use **snake_case** for method name like `list_scores` instead of `ListScores`